# How to edit Tomcat configuration files on Azure

Tags: azure, tomcat

I have a Tomcat instance running on Azure and I need to edit the server.xml and tomcat-users.xml files manually. However, I am not able to do so and I receive a 409 error saying I'm not allowed to modify the files. Is there a way to modify the files or a workaround?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a02g.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re editing the wrong file. Anything in C:\ belongs to the host and is not modifiable by the user.

You need to edit the file located in wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-version\conf folder.

See https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/tomcat-azure/configure for examples.

Comment: I saw that tutorial, however, this is the screen I get, no Tomcat files, just a default jsp page https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsZ73.png

Comment: There’s also this SO post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244868/azure-webapp-tomcat-8-configuration